# target css of parent div

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following mark up

```
<div class="xxx yyy zzz"> <!-- This div is generated by JS and the class names change all the time -->
   <div class="aaa"> Hello </div>
</div>
```

How can I target the css of the parent div without knowing the class name of the parent div using CSS only ?

```
Ex: parent.aaa { background: #fff; }
```

Comment: You cannot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1048479

Comment: You can't, CSS has no parent-selector. With JavaScript yes, CSS no. And despite what you may read elsewhere [CSS 4 does *not* offer this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles) (as currently written, at least).

Comment: you need jquery's .parent()

Comment: As people told, no CSS parent selector. For JS (jQuery for e.g.), you could create `.aaa-parent { background: #fff; }` on CSS and then on jQuery `$('.aaa').parent().addClass('aaa-parent');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector/1014958#1014958

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to target a parent of an element with CSS. Would be nice!

You could use javascript to find the element and then add a class to the parent, then style that added class:

```
// javascript - jquery
$(".aaa").parent().addClass("parentClass");

// css
.parentClass {
    ... your styles ...
}
```

Comment: Your [tag:javascript] is [tag:jquery].

Comment: Right, forgot how (justifiably) anal devs were before I typed it out. I edited to specify that it was jquery.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS there are no parent selectors, but you can use Javascript

```
element.parentNode
```